# IPv6: how do I assign a /56 if I get a /48 PD from my ISP?

Tags: ipv6

My ISP gives me a /48 prefix delegation. My home made router/firewall (Debian 8) uses wide-dhcp6c to get the PD on the external interface ("net"), it chops it into /64 prefixes that it assignes to the other interfaces ("loc" and "dmz"). Of course, `radvd` does the rest, it even uses RDNSS and DNSSL. Works like a charm.

However, I want to add a fourth interface, "guest", that will be connected to a network for my guests. On this net I want a DHCPv6 server (not strictly necessary, but hey, I'm trying to learn IPv6 here). I assume I need a prefix a bit bigger than /64 for that, because my DHCPv6-server (ISC 4.3.1 for now) needs a /64 to allow clients to do autoconfiguring. Am I right in assuming this?

It seemed logical to give a /56 to "guest", as that would give me 256 /64s, which I expect will be enough for the near future. DHCP can then hand out temporary addresses from one /64, and assign fixed addresses from another. But I can't work it out, not sure whether I miss just a small piece, or the whole point :)

This is what `dhcp6c.conf` looks like:

```
profile default {
  information-only;
  request domain-name-servers;
  request domain-name;
  script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};

interface net {
  send rapid-commit;
  send ia-na 1;
  send ia-pd 1;
};

id-assoc na 1 { };

id-assoc pd 1 {
  prefix-interface loc {
    sla-len 16;
    sla-id 1;
    ifid 1;
  };
  prefix-interface dmz {
    sla-len 16;
    sla-id 3;
    ifid 1;
  };
};
```

This takes my PD, say `2001:db8:abcd::/48`, adds the 16-bit sla-d,`0:0:0:1`, and adds the /64 host-part (ifid 1) to that: `::1`.

What I tried is to add a new `prefix-interface`, which would not configure a /64 ("sla-len 16"), but a /56 ("sla-len 8"), like this:

```
prefix-interface guest {
  sla-len 8;
  sla-id 4;
  ifid 1;
};
```

This works to some degree... It sets a /56 on the guest interface alright, but the sla-id seems to get misplaced. I had expected that if I decreased the sla-len by 8, the sla-id would be shifted 8 to the left. The sla-id would thus change from "0:0:0:1" and "0:0:0:3" (as they are on the other 2 interfaces) to "0:4:0:0". Obviously I am mistaken, because it gets to be "0:0:0:4". And that leaves me with "`2001:db8:abcd 0:0:0:4 ::1`", which means my sla-id has become part of my host part. Am I right?

I can't increase the sla-id from 4 to hex "400" (1024 in decimal), because that won't fit in the sla-len (which is only 8 and thus can't contain more than "ff", or 256 in dec). This is what the dhcp6c.conf manual says about the sla-id:

> This statement specifies the identifier value of the site-level aggregator (SLA) on the interface.  ID must be a decimal integer which fits in the length of SLA IDs (see below).  For example, if ID is 1 and the client is delegated an IPv6 prefix 2001:db8:ffff::/48, dhcp6c will combine the two values into a single IPv6 prefix, 2001:db8:ffff:1::/64, and will configure the prefix on the specified interface.

What do I do wrong? How to I get dhcp6c to configure "`0:4:0:0`" as the sla-id, or what do I have to do to make the "4" end up in the 2nd nibble instead of the 4th?

Or am I thinking in the wrong direction here? I hope I don't have to do my own prefix delegation from interface "net" to the others...

I've read quite a few articles and blogs, but I can't find anything that deals with a situation like this.

Comment: Have you considered VLANs?

Comment: I am using VLANs. The sla-id is also the VLAN-id, but don't tell anybody ;)  But how would that solve the problem?

Comment: You don't want a subnet on one VLAN to be bigger than /64. If you are using Wi-Fi, you can trunk multiple /64 VLANs to the AP, each VLAN using a different SSID. On a wired connection to  a switch, you trunk each /64 VLAN. On the router, each VLAN has a separate, virtual interface.

Comment: I'm not using WiFi here, at least not yet. The AP is going to live in the  guest LAN too, I want to keep my guests isolated. The VLANs really are below all of this, as every machine is a VM running on Xen. I use VLANs to create bridges on the hypervisor and connect those to other hypervisors.

Comment: Well, you certainly don't want to create a /56 VLAN. You probably should have one (or more, as you see fit) wired guest VLAN, one wireless (or more) guest VLAN, each a /64. With Wi-Fi, use a trunk so that the AP can't be configured from the wireless side (a separate management VLAN that doesn't go out the airwaves). I just don't see the problem you have.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is create a prefix that allows me to have one /64 available for autoconfiguration, and another in which the addresses of the servers on that LAN are (nameserver, gateway and such), and the addresses for static assignments in DHCP.

Comment: DHCP doesn't have to use the entire address range of a VLAN/subnet; you can reserve sections of the subnet for static devices. IPv6 has plenty of room in a /64 to do this. Just pick a range in the subnet for the DHCP scope. It may be best to just have a separate VLAN for servers, etc.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem I ran into was the reason for trying to create the /56. The DHCP server complained that there were no addresses available, so I figured I'd give it one dedicated /64 for temporary addresses and assign the static ones from another.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have a /48 delegated by my ISP. I have broken it down into multiple VLANs: wired, wireless, VoIP, servers, wireless management, guest wired, guest wireless, etc.  Each VLAN is a /64, and each, except the guest VLANs, has one or more DHCP scopes, but the scopes don't encompass the entire address range.  The guest VLANs are set up to use SLAAC.

This allows easy use of QoS. I have the VoIP set up as priority, and the guest VLANs have a pretty low priority.  It all works quite well, and, if you choose the subnets carefully (each type starts at a /56 boundary), you can aggregate multiple VLANS of the same type.  I don't actually have any /56 defined anywhere, just each type is in a /56 range.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a second try. It doesn't really answer the original question, though, I still don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The answer to your original questions, "Don't do that." You said you don't want to have to delegate. Personally, I wouldn't worry about DHCP on guest VLANs; let 'em use SLAAC.

Comment: I can't live with a simple "don't do that"  without understanding why ;) But you're right, DHCP is totally unnecessary, as SLAAC works like a breeze. I just wanted to get some more IPv6 under my belt.

Comment: The problem is that if you peel a /56 from your ISP's delegation, that's what you have unless you re-delegate it to be broken down later. You should just peel off /64s as you need them. It sounds like your big problem is with the DHCP server configuration.

Comment: Yup, maybe I ran away for my dhcp problem ;)  Thanks, I'll look into that again.

Comment: It's working now, with a normal /64 on "guest". Guess I missed something while configuring DHCP earlier. Thanks for your help.